# Python socket recv (client-side)

Tags: php, python, sockets

i have to connect to an api via socket and send / recv some data.
the company send me a php-example-file with this code for reading data from the socket:

```
function readAnswer() {
        $size = fgets($this->socketPtr, 64);    

        $answer = "";           
        $readed = 0;

        while($readed < $size) {
            $part = fread($this->socketPtr, $size - $readed);   
            $readed += strlen($part);
            $answer .= $part;
        }
        return $answer;
    }
```

This works for me. But in python i get from times to times an error. 
not everything from the socket is recv.
my python try looks like this:

```
def read_answer(self,the_socket,timeout=0.5):
        the_socket.setblocking(0)   
        total_data=[]
        data=''     
        begin=time.time()
        while 1:
            if total_data and time.time()-begin > timeout:
                break
            elif time.time()-begin > timeout*2:
                break
            try:
                data = the_socket.recv(8192)
                if data:
                    total_data.append(data)
                    begin=time.time()
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            except:
                pass
        return ''.join(total_data)
```

i recv data as a dict / array. and from time to time i only get a int (msg length i think)
so what would be a better way to read the data from socket. 
ah the api sends the data in a correct way, i checked this. it's only this little function ;(

After using the code below (thanks falsetru) and added a readed=len(data) i run into another problem:
this is the working php code:

```
 function _parse_answer($answerData)
        {
            $result = array();
            $lines = explode("\n", $answerData);
            $data = explode("&", $lines[0]);
            foreach($data as $piece)
            {
                $keyval = explode("=", $piece, 2);
                $result[$keyval[0]] = $keyval[1];
            }
            for($i=1;$i<count($lines);$i++)
            {
                $result["csv"][]=$lines[$i];
            }
            return $result;
        }
```

and this my crappy python code:

```
def parse_answer(self,data):
        #print "dd_demo_api: answer: (%s)" % (data)
        if data:
            result = {}
            lines = data.split("\n")
            index_list = 0
            if len(lines) == 1:
                index_list = 0
            else:
                index_list = 1
            pieces = lines[index_list].split("&")
            for x in pieces:
                keyval = x.split("=")
                result[keyval[0]] = keyval[1]
            iterlines = iter(lines)
            next(iterlines)
            next(iterlines)
            count = 1
            result["csv"] = {}
            for x in iterlines:
                result["csv"][count] = x.split(";")
            return result
        else:
            return 0
```

i think here is some optimization required? ;(

Comment: What is `answerData` here? Could you show the content of the `answerData` ?

Answer (score 1):

Python version does not do the same thing with PHP version.

Try following code:

```
def read_answer(self, sock):
    size = int(sock.recv(64).strip().rstrip('\0'))

    # Above is not exactly same as `fgets`.
    # If that causes an issue, use following instead.
    #
    # f = sock.makefile('r')
    # size = int(f.readline(64).rstrip('\0'))
    #
    # and replace `sock.recv(n)` with `f.read(n)` in the following loop.

    total_data = []
    readed = 0
    while readed < size:
        data = sock.recv(size - readed)
        if data:
            total_data.append(data)
            readed += len(data)
    return b''.join(total_data)
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the api doesn't close the connection after 1 request. i try to complete about 500 requests. so this functions blocks, i think.

Comment: @Jens, I don't think connection close is not an issue here because you said PHP version works for you. ...  Check value of `$size` in PHP and `size` in Python version.

Comment: the size is ok. its just that the script "hangs" after the first request. nothing happens.

Comment: @Jens, I'm sorry. I forgot to add `readed += len(data)`. I updated the code.